# For a group $G$ and subgroup $H$, is $a \sim b \iff a^{-1}b\in H$ an equivalence relation even when $H$ is not normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, equivalence-relations, normal-subgroups, congruence-relations

Is it true or false that defining a relation on the group $G$ based on the definition $a \sim b$ if and only if $a^{-1}b\in H$ defines an equivalence relation regardless of whether $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: This is straightforward. Do you understand the definitions of subgroup and equivalence relation?

Comment: Yes. Normality ensures it is a congruence.

Answer (score 4):

You can test it yourself. Let $H$ be an arbitrary subgroup of $G$.

- **Reflexivity:** Is it true that $a^{-1}a=1_G\in H$ for each $a\in G$?
- **Symmetry:** Suppose that $a,b\in G$, and $a^{-1}b\in H$; is it true that $b^{-1}a\in H$? HINT: What is $\left(a^{-1}b\right)^{-1}$?
- **Transitivity:** Suppose that $a,b,c\in G$, $a^{-1}b\in H$, and $b^{-1}c\in H$. Can you rewrite $a^{-1}c$ in a way that shows clearly that it’s in $H$?